# Getting resource not found exception using robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric

```
//Service class
MyService extends Service {

private SoundPool mSoundPool;
private int mSoundID;

@Override
public void onCreate(){

mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(final SoundPool soundPool, final int sampleId,
            final int status) {
        mIsSoundLoaded = true;
    }
});
    //Here I am initializing soundpool and getting resource not found exception
    // It should be context of CustomRobolectricTestRunner 
    mSoundID = mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.btn_click, 1);

}

}
```

//Service Test class

```
 @RunWith(CustomRobolectricTestRunner.class)
//@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest
{

    @Test
    public void testOnCreate()
    {
        // String hello = this.activity.getString(R.string.app_name);
        // assertThat(hello, equalTo("Plus Box"));

        MyService service = new MyService();
        service.onCreate(); // Getting exception Resource not found.

        //To cross check, I have accessed resource in the following way
        //and it working fine. I am able to access resource here.
        /*      int resourceId = Robolectric
                .getShadowApplication()
                .getResources()
                .getIdentifier("btn_click", "raw",
                        Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getPackageName());
        if (resourceId != 0)
        {
            // Raw folder contains resource.
            System.out.println("The value of Raw ID " + resourceId);
            assertTrue(true);
        }
        else
        {
            // Raw folder doesn't contain resource.
            System.out.println("The value of Raw ID " + resourceId);
            assertTrue(false);
        }
    */


    }


}
```

Even I tried to create my own custom test runner, since my application also have Application class (MyApplication).
But seems that, it always takes MyApplication context, instead of TestApplication.
I followed this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/K2q8xAFfQOA link.

```
public class TestApplication extends MyApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        createSession(UserGroup.Unknown, 0, SessionState.Active, "", 0, "");


    }

}

public class CustomRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner
        implements TestLifecycle<Application> {


    public CustomRobolectricTestRunner(final Class<?> testClass)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTest(Method arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTest(Method arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Application createApplication(Method arg0, AndroidManifest manifest) {

        TestApplication testApplication = new TestApplication();
        ShadowContextWrapper shadowApp = Robolectric.shadowOf( testApplication );
        shadowApp.setPackageName("com.example.robolectric");
        testApplication.onCreate();

        return testApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareTest(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Any help would be highly appreicated.
Regards, Yuvi

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric 2.3 has introduced a [ServiceController](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/util/ServiceController.java), similar to the ActivityController, to help drive the lifecycle of a service.

```
ServiceController<MyService> controller = Robolectric.buildService(MyService.class);
MyService service = controller.attach().create().get()
```

Or simply:

```
MyService myService = Robolectric.setupService(MyService.class);
```

Furthermore, if you would like Robolectric to use your test application class - then if your application class is named 'MyApplication', name your test application class 'TestMyApplication' and place it in the same package under your test directory. By prepending "Test" to the class name, it tells Robolectric to use the TestMyApplication for your tests. (Reference: http://robolectric.blogspot.ca/2013/04/the-test-lifecycle-in-20.html)

Comment: Hi, you interpret my question wrongly. I have added more code snippet.
I am not gonna to test or mock SoudPool related classes which are from Android framework. I want to do unit test of MyService class.